# Mod_rewrite rule to redirect from a specific path to another is completely ignored

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect http://1.2.3.4/foo to http://1.2.3.4/WebFOO. The rule that I've created looks like this in ApacheRoot\conf\httpd.conf:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?foo /WebFOO [R,L]
```

However, this approach doesn't work even though this rule is syntactically correct. Means I connect to http://1.2.3.4/foo and get a 404 or the specific content for "/foo". Note: to test things out I've created a folder with a simple index.html in (htdocs/foo). This actually prevented the 404 of course but still the redirection did not take place.

The virtual-host portion looks like this and is beneath the mod-rewrite rule:

```
ServerName 1.2.3.4
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 1.2.3.4:80
  #Redirect permanent / https://1.2.3.4/
</VirtualHost>
```

Why is that redirection completely ignored? Am I able to check somehow whether the server at least recognizes the rule (no rewrite-entries so far in the error.log)?

Note: To be sure about the syntactical correctness of the rule I've also tested it with http://htaccess.madewithlove.be:

[image: Rewrite rule tester result]

Not only this test worked fine but also things like `/foo/index.html`. It was correctly translated into `/WebFOO/index.html`.

Note: Enabling the verbose logging as suggested by one of a mod_rewrite canonical question's [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/214675/375276) is not suitable for apache 2.4:

- The [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/214675/375276) states:

> For more complex rules, use mod_rewrite's RewriteLog directive to log
>   activity to a file and set RewriteLogLevel 3

- [StackOverflow states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632952/2641361):

> Since Apache httpd 2.4 mod_rewrite RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel
>   directives has been completely replaced by the new per-module logging
>   configuration.
>
> `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6`

- The [API approves](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging):

> RewriteLog
>
> Those familiar with earlier versions of mod_rewrite will no doubt be
>   looking for the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel directives. This
>   functionality has been completely replaced by the new per-module
>   logging configuration mentioned above. To get just the
>   mod_rewrite-specific log messages, pipe the log file through grep:
>   tail -f error_log|fgrep '[rewrite:'

- I don't have any `[rewrite:` entries in my ApacheRoot\logs\error.log

Comment: Where is this... server config or per-directory / .htaccess file? Any other directives? Define "doesn't work" - error? Nothing? Something else?

Comment: @w3d I've added the information to the question :) Do you need any additional information?

Comment: Try removing the `<IfModule>` wrapper... do you get an error? (Unless this is intended to work without mod_rewrite, then you don't need the wrapper.)

Comment: @w3d Hm, very good idea but didn't help :/ I've added the result to the question. Also checked the error-log which also doesn't state anything.

Comment: "Note: to test things out I've created a folder with a simple index.html in (htdocs/foo)" - If you've created a _folder_ called `foo` then this may not match since mod_dir (`DirectorySlash` default config) will try to fix the URL by appending a slash (301 redirect - which is likely to be cached). mod_dir generally fires _before_ mod_rewrite, so the URL-path that mod_rewrite sees is likely to end in a slash.

Comment: @w3d Sorry, didn't get that one. Can you try to explain it once again? :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/foo$ WebFOO [R]
> ```

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/?foo /WebFoo [R,L]
```

Comment: Nope did not work... still get a 404 when connecting to https://a.domain/foo

Comment: Have you restarted your server? Otherwise, this should be doing _something_, provided it's in the correct place in the config file? Is it near the top of a VirtualHost container for port 443 (HTTPS)? Remove the `<IfModule>` wrapper... do you get an error?

Comment: Yep, I went into services.msc and restarted the apache service via a right-click. Actually it's a q-system and therefore we don't have https up and running. I just wanted to avoid "why do you use http"-discussions^^ However, the virtualhost portion is on line 252 whereas mod_rewrite portion is on 178. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you define the RewriteRule outside of the vHost? Try to define the Rule inside the vHost.
I'd also correct the ServerName inside the vHost to:

```
ServerName 1.2.3.4
```

Also the LogLevel part should be inside the vHost. 
To see if the Rewrite is working check with the Chrome Developer Tools, There you can check if you get a 301. Maybe you get the 404 after the redirect?